# Problem with popover overlaying some of my component

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, overlay, uipopovercontroller

I'm using a popover to display information about the object the user clicked on. 
The problem is that sometimes this popover goes on top of a graphical component that need to stay visible.

The solution would be to **tell my UIPopverController to be displayed strictly inside a specific zone** even if the anchor point is at the border of this zone (the same thing that is happening when a popover need to be displayed near screen borders).

Setting the view as the popover container doesn't work as the popover can be displayed out of it :

```
[self.aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:popOverFrame inView:self.textView
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

Do you know how to do that ?

Note that my objects are not buttons so I can't use the function

```
– presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try taking the object you don't want obscured, get its frame and use that as the rect in `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`. iOS generally tries to avoid obscuring the origin rect.

Comment: No I don't have an answer yet. The thing is that I want my popover to point out a zone A without being on a zone B.
I'm not sure there is something in the API right now to do that.